# diy compression of a image giving a previous frame (Inter-frame compression)

Tags: python, numpy, raspberry-pi, compression, video-streaming

Is there any way i can compress a numpy image giving a previous frame

I wanna do a sort of DIY video live stream for my 3d printed rc car (Newone) from my raspberry pi.

currently Iam sending continuously jpgs without any Inter-frame compression. It would be cool to have a sort of motion prediction, which would save lot of traffic

```py
npImg = cap.read()[1] # capturing image
npImg=cv2.resize(npImg,(320,180))# downsize the image for stream
jImg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', npImg, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),90])[1]# numpy image to jpg
stream = io.BytesIO(jImg)# creating a stream to continuously taking chunks from the jpg file
while run:
    part = stream.read(504)# 506 is the max UDP package lengh, minus 2 for video authentification
    if not part: break# if-block will execute if string is empty; breaks the loop
    soc.sendto(b'v'+part,address_server)
soc.sendto(b'f', address_server) #img finished
```

Comment: This has been worked on for over 30 years now with highly efficient and effective codecs having been developed, and that are widely available. Why in the world would you want to do it yourself?

Comment: actually its really hard to realize a video stream in python, options are WebRTC and gstreamer and both are not easy to setup. i am just trying to split a problem into two (compression and streaming). i don't want to DIY a compression i search for a solution to access last frame of a compression

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/